# so i'm currently making a chess game using assembly 8086 and i was asking how can i draw the grid of the game and the pieces?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

[chessgrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JziUh.png)

I tried to draw the grid line by line but it was too difficult and I don't know how to draw the pieces

Comment: Cut out the pieces using an image editor, export as bitmap with transparency. Embed the files or convert to data array. Drawing the checkerboard is trivial but you can of course also save that as an image.

Comment: Your emulator's video "hardware" will demand a certain format, you'll need to figure out what that is before you can get a definitive answer. It's going to depend on what video mode you're in.